# Выборка из базы (form select)

Tags: php

```
Есть таблица с автомобилями

Есть select с марками машин

<select name="marks">
    <option>Выберите марку</option>
    <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    ................

</select>

Когда юзер выбирает определенную марку, ему показывается авто этой марки

Внимание! Вопрос!

Как показать список всех машин, если юзер не выберет ни одну из марок? Т.е. оставит выбраном <option>Выберите марку</option>
```

Comment: Сделайте выборку SELECT без условия WHERE = <марка авто>

Comment: я хочу одним запросов все сделать. 
    SELECT title FROM auto WHERE marks = $marks

Answer (score 2):

```
<select name="marks">
    <option value="%">Выберите марку</option>
    <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    ................

</select>

SELECT title FROM auto WHERE marks LIKE $marks
```

Ограничение: marks должно быть char или varchar

Comment: LIKE "%$marks%" не так?

Comment: Не так. Знак % означает любую последовательность символов. В данном же случае вам нужно выбрать конкретную марку. Представьте, что у вас есть марки ab и abc. Тогда при $marks = "ab" запрос с %$marks% выберет и ab, и abc.

Comment: спасибо! работает!

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, сделайте у `<option>Выберите марку</option>` `value="BMW,AUDI,HONDA..."` и т. д., т. е. перечислите все имеющиеся марки автомобилей. Тогда запрос будет выглядеть как `SELECT title FROM auto WHERE marks IN ($marks)`. Путь крайне нежелательный, т. к. во-первых вам придётся отдельным запросом вытаскивать марки всех автомобилей, а во-вторых передавать в sql-запрос данные, полученные непосредственно со страницы нежелательно - это потенциальная уязвимость к sql-инъекции. На вашем месте я бы не поленился и просто написал дополнительный if.

Comment: хм...суровое решение